# Batch file with switches

Tags: batch-file

During the recent break I looked over my mirror.bat.

It’s was cobbled together over many years.

It’s not pretty.  It needs a really good tidy up.

It current works with robocopy job files, eg:
› mirror.bat /Mirror "Mirror HDD to USB"

The way it should work is to allow me to use multiple switches.

For example:

1. to mirror my hard drive, clean cache, dismount all drives and hibernate, it would be nice to enter
   › mirror.bat /Mirror "Mirror HDD to USB" /Clean /Dismount /Hibernate
2. to clean cache and dismount
   › mirror.bat /Clean /Dismount

My chosen switches are: /Clean /Dismount /Hibernate /Mirror /Help

These should change to: /C /D /H /M /H /?

Some small utilities help out:
• http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html
• http://uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html

So, the important components are:
• call profile standardisation: color, %temp%, etc.
• define switches
• create menu
• create error screen
• use robocopy job files
• clear cache, temp, etc.
• dismount all non-system drives
• hibernate

Thanks in anticipation of a great discussion.

mirror.bat

```
:: ----------------
:: Start common setting - should be called from a common.bat
:: ----------------
@echo off && cls
EndLocal && SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd %~dp0

set profile="All Stuff"
set comment="Mirror to USB, clean cache, hibernate"
set slash=Clean Dismount Hibernate Mirror Help
set colour=color F0
set errclr=color 4F
set div=úúúúúúúúúúúúúúúú
set rule=ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ

set favicon="\favicon.ico"
set drives=C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
set eject=G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
set dvd=D
set symlink=MMC SDCard
set exfldr="MSOCache" "$RECYCLE.BIN" "RECYCLED" "RECYCLER" "System Volume Information" "TEMP" "TMP" "%tmp%"
set exext="*.~*" "*_list.txt" "*.log" "*.tmp" "*.xlk"

set app.1="%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe"
set app.2="\PortableApps\NirSoft\NirCmd.exe"
set opt.1=-1 100
set opt.2=-1 20
set opt.3=30
set app.3="\PortableApps\Uwe-Sieber\RemoveDrive.exe"
set app.4="\PortableApps\Uwe-Sieber\EjectMedia.exe"
set app.6="%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe"
set ext.1=.RCJ
set swt.1=/job:
set app.7="%SystemRoot%\System32\shutdown.exe"

%colour%
set no=1
:TEST
set test=!app.%no%!
if NOT exist !test! set app=!test! && goto :ERROR
if exist !test! for %%a in (!test!) do (
  set app.!no!=%%~fa
  set /a no+=1
) else (
  set app.!no!=
  goto :NEXT
)
goto :TEST
:NEXT
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('time /t') do (set time=%%i %%j)
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do (set date=%%i %%j/%%k/%%l)
set title=%profile:"=% %~nx0 Ä %date%  %time%
set lock="%tmp%\%profile:"=%_%~n0.lock"
if defined lock if exist %lock% goto :ERROR
set endwait=%app.2% wait %opt.3%00
set endbeep=%app.2% speak text "bong" %opt.1%
set bing=%app.2% speak text "bing" %opt.1%
set hipip=%app.2% speak text "bang" %opt.1%
set lopip=%app.2% speak text "bung" %opt.1%
:: ----------------
:: End common setting - should be called from a common.bat
:: ----------------
set message="¯ Press C to continue, D to "delay" for %opt.3% seconds or B to break "%~nx0": "
set choices=cdb
set default=c
set select=%app.1" /t %opt.3% /c:%choices% /d %default% /n /m %message%
set sel.2=%opt.3% second delay
set sel.1=continue
set sel.0=break (terminate) the batch file
:CONDITIONS
if {%1}=={} set s.act=Help && goto :/HELP
if {%1}=={/} set s.act=Help && goto :/HELP
set speak=%app.2% %bing%
set arg.1=%1
if NOT {%arg.1%}=={} (
  set ref.1=%arg.1:"=%
)
if {%ref.1%}=={/?} set s.act=Help && goto :/HELP
if {%ref.1:~,1%}=={/} set s.act=%ref.1%
if NOT {%s.act%}=={} (
  set s.act=Help 
  set speak=%app.2% speak text "%s.act%" %opt.1%
  for %%a in (%slash%) do if "%s.act%"=="/%%a" (
    set s.act=%%a
    set speak=%app.2% speak text "%%a" %opt.1%
  )
  goto :/%s.act%
)

:/CLEAN
set comment=deleting temporary files and folders
title %s.act% Ä %title%
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cls && echo. && echo   %s.act% Ä %comment% && echo   %rule%
set cleaner=
for %%C in (
  "%app.2% script "~$folder.nircmd$\NirCmd.ncl""
) do set cleaner=!cleaner! %%C
:CLEANGO
echo. && echo   Cleaners for %UserName% on %ComputerName%
set /a nr=0
set clist=
for %%C in (%cleaner%) do (
  set /a nr+=1
  set clist=!clist! %%C
  echo. && echo      !nr!. %%~C
)
echo. && echo   %rule%
:CLEAN_loop
%speak% && %select%
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.0% && echo. && goto :BREAK
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.2% && echo. && goto :CLEAN_loop
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.1% && echo. && goto :CLEAN_end
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.0% && echo. && goto :END
:CLEAN_end
cls
echo. && echo   %s.act% Ä %comment% && echo   %rule%
echo. && echo   Cleaning %UserName% on %ComputerName%
set /a nr=0
for %%C in (%clist%) do (
  set /a nr+=1
  %%~C
  echo. && echo      !nr!. %%~C
)
echo.
for %%s in (
  s.act comment cleaner nr clist speak
) do set %%s=
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
echo   %rule% && %endbeep% && %endwait% && goto :END

:/DISMOUNT
set comment=safely remove portable drives and devices
title %s.act% Ä %title%
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cls && echo. && echo   %s.act% Ä %comment% && echo   %rule%
:DISMOUNTGO
echo. && echo   %s.act% Ä %comment% && echo   %rule%
echo. && echo   Drives on \\%ComputerName%\%UserName%
echo.
set /a nr=0
set dlist=
for %%d in (%drives%) do (
  if exist %%d:\nul (
    echo @echo off > volume.bat
    echo set getvol_= >> volume.bat
    echo set getvol_=%%3:   %%5 %%6 %%7 %%8 %%9 >> volume.bat
    vol %%d: | find "Volume" > volume.cmd
    call volume.cmd
    if exist volume.* del volume.*
    set dlist=!dlist! %%d
    set /a nr+=1
    if !nr! LEQ  9 (
      echo      !nr!.  !getvol_!
    ) else (
      echo     !nr!.  !getvol_!
    )
  )
)
echo. && echo   %rule%
:DISMOUNT_loop
%speak% && %select%
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.0% && echo. && goto :BREAK
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.2% && echo. && goto :DISMOUNT_loop
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.1% && echo. && goto :DISMOUNT_end
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.0% && echo. && goto :END
:DISMOUNT_end
cls
echo. && echo   %s.act% Ä %comment% && echo   %rule%
echo. && echo   Dismounting removable devices for %UserName% on %ComputerName%
echo.
set /a nr=0
if exist volume.* del volume.*
for %%d in (%dlist%) do (
  if exist removing.* del removing.*
  if exist %%d:\nul (
    echo @echo off > removing.bat
    echo set get_vol= >> removing.bat
    echo set get_vol=%%2 %%3 %%4 %%5 %%6 %%7 %%8 %%9 >> removing.bat
    %app.3% %%d: > removing.txt
    if !errorlevel! EQU  0 (
      type removing.txt | find "Removing" > removing.cmd
      call removing.cmd
      if exist removing.* del removing.*
      set /a nr+=1
      if !nr! LEQ  9 (
        echo      !nr!.  !get_vol! && %hipip%
      ) else (
        echo     !nr!.  !get_vol! && %hipip%
      )
      if !errorlevel! EQU  4 echo           code !errorlevel! : temporary copy created, executed and deleted
      if !errorlevel! EQU  3 echo           code !errorlevel! : -- code not defined --
      if !errorlevel! EQU  2 echo           code !errorlevel! : INVALID device or parameter
      if !errorlevel! EQU  1 echo           code !errorlevel! : not found - NOT removed
      if !errorlevel! EQU  0 echo           code !errorlevel! : REMOVED successfully
      echo.
    )
  )
)
if exist removing.* del removing.*
for %%e in (%dvd%) do (
  if exist ejecting.* del ejecting.*
  if exist %%e:\nul (
    echo @echo off > ejecting.bat
    echo set get_vol= >> ejecting.bat
    echo set get_vol=%%3 %%4 %%5 %%6 %%7 %%8 %%9 >> ejecting.bat
    %app.4% %%e: > ejecting.txt
    if !errorlevel! EQU  0 (
      type ejecting.txt | find "Ejecting" > ejecting.cmd
      call ejecting.cmd
      if exist ejecting.* del ejecting.*
      set /a nr+=1
      echo      !nr!.   !get_vol! && %hipip%
      if !errorlevel! EQU  4 echo           code !errorlevel! : temporary copy created, executed and deleted
      if !errorlevel! EQU  3 echo           code !errorlevel! : -- code not defined --
      if !errorlevel! EQU  2 echo           code !errorlevel! : INVALID device or parameter
      if !errorlevel! EQU  1 echo           code !errorlevel! : not found - NOT ejected
      if !errorlevel! EQU  0 echo           code !errorlevel! : EJECTED successfully
      echo.
    )
  )
)
if !nr! EQU 0 echo      !nr!  removable devices dismounted && echo. && %lopip%
if exist ejecting.* del ejecting.*
for %%s in (
  s.act comment title nr dlist drives get_vol dvd
) do set %%s=
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
echo   %rule% && %endbeep% && %endwait% && goto :/CLEAN

:/MIRROR
set comment=file replication
title %s.act% Ä %title%
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cls && echo. && echo   %s.act% Ä %comment% && echo   %rule%
if NOT exist "%~2%ext.1%" goto :MIRRORERROR
if NOT /==/%2 if NOT %2/==/?/ goto :MIRRORGO
:MIRRORERROR
%errclr%
:NORCJ_loop
if NOT /==/%2 if NOT %2/==/?/ if NOT exist "%~2%ext.1%" (
  echo ž   Source: "%~2%ext.1%"        MISSING && echo             %div% && %lopip%
)
shift /2
if %2'==' goto :NORCJ_End
goto :NORCJ_loop
:NORCJ_end
echo. && echo ¯   Syntax: "%~nx0%" /%s.act% "source"
echo. && echo   Required: "source" Ä "%s.act% job file name" (without "%ext.1%")
echo. && echo      Notes: labels with spaces must be "double quoted"
echo. && echo   Executed: %~nx0 %*
goto :MIRRORSTOP_loop
:MIRRORSTOP_loop
echo   %rule%
%speak% && %select%
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.0% && echo. && goto :BREAK
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.2% && echo. && goto :MIRRORSTOP_loop
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.1% && echo. && goto :END
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.0% && echo. && goto :END
:MIRRORSTOP_end
:MIRRORGO
echo. && echo   %s.act% job list...
set /a nr=0
set /a step=0
set joblist=
:MIRROR_loop
set /a nr+=1
set jobfile=%2
set rcjob="%jobfile:"=%"
%app.2% speak text %jobfile% %opt.1%
echo. && echo     %nr%. %rcjob%
set joblist=%joblist% %rcjob%
for /f "tokens=2* delims=:" %%s in ('find "/sd:" "%~2%ext.1%"') do set srcdir=%%s:%%t
for /f "tokens=1* delims=   " %%s in ("%srcdir%") do set srcdir=%%s
if exist "%srcdir%*" (
  echo. && echo        ¯ %srcdir%        ready && set /a step+=1 && %hipip%
  for %%j in (%symlink%) do (
    if NOT exist %srcdir:~,3%%%~j\* (
      echo. && echo          ž %srcdir:~,3%%%~j        NOT mounted
            && echo          %div% && %lopip%
      set swt.1=/xd "%%~j" !swt.1!
    )
  )
) else (
  echo. && echo        ž %SrcDir%        MISSING 
        && echo        %div% && %lopip%
)
  for /f "tokens=2* delims=:" %%d in ('find "/dd:" "%~2%ext.1%"') do set destdir=%%d:%%e
  for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%d in ("%destdir%") do set destdir=%%d
  if exist "%destdir%*" (
    echo. && echo        ¯ %destdir%        ready && set /a step+=1 && %hipip%
    for %%k in (%symlink%) do (
      if NOT exist %destdir:~,3%%%~k\* (
        echo. && echo          ž %destdir:~,3%%%~k        NOT mounted 
              && echo          %div% && %lopip%
        set swt.1=/xd "%%~k" !swt.1!
      )
    )
  ) else (
    echo. && echo        ž %destdir%        MISSING 
          && echo        %div% && %lopip%
  )
  shift /2
  if %2'==' goto :MIRROR_end
  goto :MIRROR_loop
:MIRROR_end
echo.
set /a total=2*%nr%
if %step% LSS %total% (
  echo ž Problem: %step% out of %total% steps ready Ä check connections, etc.
  goto :MIRRORSTOP_loop
)
echo   %rule%
:MIR_loop
%speak% && %select%
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %select0% && echo. && goto :BREAK
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %select2% && echo. && goto :MIR_loop
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %select1% && echo. && goto :MIR_end
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %select0% && echo. && goto :END
:MIR_end
cls
echo. && echo   %s.act% Ä %comment% && echo   %rule%
echo. && echo   Mirroring data for %UserName% on %ComputerName%
echo.
set /a nr=0
for %%j in (%joblist%) do (
  set /a nr+=1
  title %%f Ä %s.act% Ä %date%  %time%
  echo     !nr!. %%j
  %app.6% %swt.1%%%f 
  echo. echo   %rule% && %endbeep% && %endwait%
)
for %%s in (
  s.act comment nr step joblist jobfile rcjob opt.1 srcdir symlink swt.1 destdir speak
) do set %%s=
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
goto :/CLEAN

:/HIBERNATE
set comment=hibernate Windows
title %s.act% Ä %title%
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cls && echo. && echo   %s.act% Ä %comment% && echo   %rule%
set hibernate=%app.7% /h 
echo. && echo   %rule%
:HBNGO
echo. && echo   Hibernate %UserName% on %ComputerName%
echo. && echo   ¯ %Hibernate%
echo. && echo   %rule%
:HBNTASK_loop
%Speak% && %select%
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.0% && echo. && goto :BREAK
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.2% && echo. && goto :HBNTASK_loop
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.1% && echo. && goto :HBNTASK_end
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.0% && echo. && goto :END
:HBNTASK_end
cls
echo. && echo   %s.act% Ä %comment% && echo   %rule%
echo. && echo   Hibernate for %UserName% on %ComputerName%
%hibernate%
echo.
for %%s in (
  s.act comment hibernate speak
) do set %%s=
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
echo   %rule% && %endbeep% && %endwait% && goto :END

:/HELP
set comment= ber batch file
title %s.act% Ä %title%
%errclr%
cls && echo. && echo   %s.act% Ä %comment% && echo   %rule%
echo. && echo       File: "%~f0"
echo. && echo ¯   Syntax: "%batch%" /Switch "Command" "Command" ...
echo. && echo   Switches: (case sensitive)
for %%s in (%slash%) do echo             /%%s
echo. && echo  More help: "%batch%" /Switch /?
echo. && echo      Notes: "Command" Ä some switches require an extra "command" or 2
echo             - labels with spaces must be "double quoted"
echo. && echo   Executed: %~n0 %*
goto :STOP_loop
:STOP_loop
echo   %ruleoff%
%speak% && %select%
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.0% && echo. && goto :BREAK
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.2% && echo. && goto :STOP_loop
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.1% && echo. && goto :END
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 @echo ÿÿItem %errorlevel% Ä %sel.0% && echo. && goto :END
:STOP_end

:BREAK
echo ¯ Press any key to quit this window.
pause > nul
goto :END

:END
popd
for %%s in (
  profile comment slash colour errclr div rule
  favicon drives eject dvd symlink exfldr exext
  app.1 app.2 app.3 app.4 app.5 app.6 app.7
  opt.1 opt.2 opt.3 ext.1 swt.1
  no test time date title lock endwait endbeep bing hipip lopip
  message choices default select sel.0 sel.1 sel.2
) do set %%s=
EndLocal

EXIT
```

Mirror HDD to USB.RCJ

```
/sd:E:\
/dd:J:\
/xd
    E:\FILES\Home Videos
    J:\FILES\Home Videos
/s
/copy:DAT
/dcopy:T
/timfix
/purge
/fft
/r:12
/w:5
/np
/tee
/ts
/log+:..\Logs\Mirror.LOG
/job:Global Exclusions.RCJ
```

Comment: What, *specifically* are you asking for help about?

Comment: This question belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).